# MYSQL: Counting category instances only if the user is unique

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a bit lost in this MySQL query problem which involves counting each instance of `cust.category` grouped by the branch which delivered the customer's order. If a customer has multiple orders in the same month, the `cust.category` is added according to how many orders they might have made. Is it possible to limit the counting of `cust.category` only to **unique** users?

Sample table

```
Customer table
    id  name    category   nearestbranch  created            
------  ------  ---------  -------------  -------------------
     1  John    Engineer               3  2014-09-10 18:10:10
     2  Mary    Developer              4  2014-09-10 18:10:10
-------------------------------------------------------------

Orders table
    id  delivery_date  customer_id
------  -------------  -----------
     1  2014-09-01               1
     2  2014-09-02               2
     3  2014-09-03               1
-----------------------------------
```

My query:

```
SELECT cust.nearestbranch,
    SUM(IF(cust.category = 'Engineer', 1, 0)) eng,
    SUM(IF(cust.category = 'Developer', 1, 0)) dev
    FROM customers cust
    LEFT JOIN orders ON cust.id = orders.customer_id
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(orders.delivery_date, '%Y-%m') = '2014-09'
    GROUP BY cust.nearestbranch
```

But instead of getting this (eng = 1)

```
nearestbranch     eng   dev  
-------------  ------  ------
            3       1       0
            4       0       1
```

I get this (eng = 2)

```
nearestbranch     eng   dev  
-------------  ------  ------
            3       2       0
            4       0       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)` with case so for every category you will have count of distinct users

```
SELECT cust.nearestbranch,
    COUNT(distinct case when cust.category = 'Engineer' then customer_id end) eng,
    COUNT(distinct case when cust.category = 'Developer'then customer_id end) dev
    FROM customers cust
    LEFT JOIN orders ON cust.id = orders.customer_id
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(orders.delivery_date, '%Y-%m') = '2014-09'
    GROUP BY cust.nearestbranch
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e4d2f/2)

Comment: Amazing! It works. Although I'm very cautious about using `distinct`. Doesn't it use a lot more resources or so I've heard?

Comment: @enchance i guess i will not affect your query why don't your run this query on your production server also index columns in on clause will be better, also change where clause `WHERE orders.delivery_date >= '2014-09-01' AND orders.delivery_date <= '2014-09-30'` reason of doing this if you have an index on delivery_date this where clause will use it as in your current index will not be used  see [*sargable*])(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) for reference, regards